# R predict single row

Tags: r, matrix, pca, prediction, cross-validation

I'm trying to predict some data from PCA using leave-one-out (LOO) cross validation.

The `prcomp` goes well, however when I come to `predict` the function gets upset

> error: 'newdata' must be a matrix or data frame

because I'm supplying a vector (i.e. a single row) and not a matrix (i.e. multiple rows).

I've tried `as.data.frame` and `as.matrix` and various varieties thereof but I still get errors

> error: 'newdata' does not have named columns matching one or more of the original columns`

In my example here `loo` is the LOO index and `mydata` and `myinfo` contain the data and metadata respectively.

```
tdata = mydata[-loo,]
tinfo = myinfo[-loo,]

vdata = mydata[loo,]
vinfo = myinfo[loo,]

p = prcomp( tdata )
predict(p, newdata = vdata )
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `colnames` after doing `as.data.frame`? `colnames(vdata) <- colnames(tdata)`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that because R treats 1xn and nx1 matrixes the same the data frame ends up with just 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found it:

```
predict(p, newdata = as.data.frame(t(vdata)) )
```